# [Linux]: Error in insmod - "invalid module format"

Tags: module, format, kernel, cross-compiling

I was trying to cross compile a kernel module code available in internet. My development PC is Linux 2.6.31 and my target architecture is ARM with Linux 2.6.32 kernel. My toolchain is Code Sourcery arm-none-linux-gnueabi. My Makefile looks something like this:-

```
obj-m := mymodule.o
KDIR := /path/to/target/2.6.32/kernel

all:
$(MAKE) ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
$(MAKE) ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

My Linux 2.6.32 kernel is just a source tree; not configured or built; just untarred the kernel source obtained from the vendor. Module built fine.

But when I tried to insmod the module, it shows "Invalid module format". My query is:-
Is this because that I am not building against running kernel and building against a kernel source tree which is not configured/built yet? Could anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Thanks,
Lullaby